# Replace from the current position to the end of the line

Tags: substitute

Is there a way to search and replace from a specific position in the line to the end of this line?

```
I am here and you are there
         ^
```

I tried to show cursor position with ^. For instance, I don't need to replace `here` which is before the cursor and want to replace the second one (which is a part of `there`)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using visual mode.

In normal mode (with the cursor where you want it)

`v$` (Start visual mode and move to end of line)

`Esc` (Move back to normal mode)

`:s/\%Vhere/xxxx/g` (The substitute command needed)

The important part is the `\%V`, you can read more about it here:

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_only_over_a_visual_range
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

Comment: Thanks, it works